# Pygame Platform & Player collisions

Tags: platformer, pygame

I am trying to create a platform game where a player jumps between platforms horizontally (using a projectile curve). Currently, I have a class that blits platforms and a background, as well as the player. However, I cannot get it to detect when a platform and the player collide. I have used actual images and then done self.rect = self.image.get_rect() for both the platform and the character. My question is have I done something wrong with my theory or have I just not coded it correctly.

Comment: `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` I suppose this makes it so that you know where the player and the platform rectangles are. Did you actually used those rectangles to check if the player's rect's overlaps the paltforms?

Comment: you didn't show code so we can't say if you coded it correctly. This problem is broad and without code it is useless. You should check pygame documentation. `pygame.Rect()` has functions like  `one_rect.colliderect(other_rect)` to check collision between two rectangles. Maybe better see [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php) and [platform examples](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=pl#section_38_4) especially [platform_jumper.py](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=platform_jumper.py)

Answer (score 0):

if the level is just an image then you should use masks
mask tutorial

```
mask1 = pygame.mask.from_surface(surf1)
mask2 = pygame.mask.from_surface(surf2)
m = mask1.overlap(mask2,(level.x-player.x,level.y-player.y))
```

Comment: Did you intend for the text "mask tutorial" to be a link to a tutorial about this topic?